# How to add top level element to XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple XML, that I want to add a new root to. The current root is `<myFields>` and I want to add `<myTable>` so it would look like.

```
<myTable>
    <myFields>
    .
    .
    </myFields>
</myTable>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the most likely shortest solution. :) It is also correct!

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work for you...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <myTable>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </myTable>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: almost works, but there are not longer any child elements, only values

Comment: @Marsharks and @Ryan Berger: Do note that this outputs strange results when there is some PI before root element...

Comment: yes, I saw that. Mine is an InfoPath form. My solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

**This is probably the shortest solution** :)  :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <myTable> 
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()" /> 
        </myTable> 
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <myTable>
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </myTable>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: Copy everything (**also PIs before root element**), and add `myTable` befere *root element*.

Answer (score 0):

you helped get me close enough

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="myTable">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you care to preserve any comments or processing-instructions that might be before the document element, then @Ryan Berger's solution is the way to go.